# on change submit form does not pass the changed value with the form

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to submit a form when a radio button is clicked.
The code below works fine in all browsers I've tested so far, except in Safari.

In Safari, when I click on the radio button, it seems to submit the form before actually registering the value of the new selected item.

Here's an example.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" checked="checked">radio button 1
<input type="radio" value="2">radio button 2
<input type="radio" value="3">radio button 3
```

JS:

```
$j('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    $j(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

If I click on radio button 2 or radio button 3, the form is submitted, but it's submitted with **value of 1**, not the value of the radio button that I clicked.

This problem is not limited to radio buttons.  I have the same problem with select boxes.  When I change the value, the form submits, but it submits with the old value.

EDIT
HTML

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="someurl" method="post">
<label><input checked="checked" id="1" name="cart[location_id]" type="radio" value="1">radio button 1</label>
<label><input id="2" name="cart[location_id]" type="radio" value="2">radio button 2</label>
</form>
```

ANOTHER TRY JS
This also does not work

```
$j('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    $j('input[name="cart[location_id]"]').val($j(this).val());
    $j(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: because `<input type="radio" value="1" checked="checked">` is checked

Comment: I had this problem once can you include your full form tag as well

Comment: @Shehary I really don't think that is the problem... then it wouldn't have worked in any other browser.

Comment: @joyBlanks edited my post to show the form tag.

Comment: It looks like it works if I add an onClick event to the element.  So maybe I will go that route instead of using onchange.

Comment: I lied.... the onclick on the button, also doesn't work.  it submits the form, but doesn't register the new value.

Comment: i've changed my code to not submit with the radio button, but submit with a standard submit button.... it's still not working.   it must be something in safari that's causing this crap.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shehary said - your HTML is defining which radio button is submitting its value on the form with 'checked="checked"' while your JS is only responsible for causing the form to submit on any radio button being clicked.

You will probably want to add conditions to ensure which ever input was selected has the correct checked value before the .submit()

```
$j('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    $j('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked').prop('checked', false);
    $j(this).prop('checked', true);
    $j(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with your suggestion.  I've added alert boxes to show the selected value. It never changes.  It's always 1. [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/narfie/m6ehejzj/1/)

Comment: btw.. if I use `$j('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked').prop('checked', false);` I get an error in the console $j(...).attr(...).prop(...) is not a function.

Comment: I can see your issue. I don't think it will help as your limited to what your form reports on its submission - but the correct value can still be retreived with: `$j('input[name="cart[location_id]"]:checked').val()` as can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/m6ehejzj/40/

Answer (score 0):

So, we have tried absolutely everything.  The problem does not seem to be with the code or with the browser.  The problem is on the machine. (macbook air)
We've tried submitting the normal way with a submit button in safari, chrome and firefox.  On all other machines in these browsers (even on mobile devices) it works.  Just not on this machine.

So, I'm gonna close this thread 'cause I don't think we're gonna find the answer here.

Thanx for all the help anyway!